# Remove plus sign (+) from string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use `preg_replace()` to remove a plus sign (`+`) from my string. I used

```
$variation = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $variation);
```

But that removed periods (`.`) too, which I need it in the string. Is there a way to just remove the plus sign?

Comment: `preg_replace('/\+/', '', $string);`

Comment: `str_replace('+', '', $string);`

Comment: These strings wouldn't happen to be just numbers would they?  "+2.87"

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes they are just numbers. Also I will need to remove the dollar sign ($)

Comment: @OP Please note the number of votes on the simple `str_replace()` comment above.  This is not a problem that requires regex, so regex is an unneccessarily non-optimal solution.

Comment: @MikeBrant Exactly. Either `str_replace` or `strtr` will do just fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although the original answer to this question does achieve the intended effect, it is not the most efficient way to do this simple task.  As noted in the comments above, the use of `str_replace()` is preferred in this case.

```
$variation = str_replace("+", "", $variation);
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

This works to remove **only** a plus sign:

```
$variation = preg_replace(/[+]/, "", $variation);
```

You can see it work here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1Fb  (be sure you select the preg_replace function)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a problem that needs regex solution at all.

Comment: Thanks Crackertastic.Regex helped me a lot

Answer (score 6):

For `+$7.99` maybe:

```
$string = ltrim($string, '+$');
```

Or if for whatever reason they are at either ends use `trim()`.

Answer (score 4):

You really don't need regular expressions, given `$value = '+$2.47';`:

```
$value = (float) strtr($value, [
    '$' => '',
    '+' => '',
]);

var_dump($value); // double(2.47)
```

Note the `(float)` cast; I assume this may be advantageous seeing as you're working with numeric values.

Alternatively, if you're hell-bent on using `preg_replace` then match a negated class:

```
$value = (float) preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/', '', $value);

var_dump($value); // double(2.47)
```

This will replace any non-numeric non-dot (`.`) characters.