# Remove empty space and plus sign from the beginning of a string

Tags: php

I have a string that begins with an empty space and a `+` sign :

```
$s = ' +This is a string[...]';
```

I can't figure out how to remove the first `+` sign using PHP. I've tried `ltrim`, `preg_replace` with several patterns and with trying to escape the `+` sign, I've also tried `substr` and `str_replace`. None of them is removing the plus sign at the beginning of the string. Either it doesn't replace it or it remplace/remove the totality of the string. Any help will be highly appreciated!

**Edit :** After further investigation, it seems that it's not really a plus sign, it looks 100% like a `+` sign but I think it's not. Any ideas for how to decode/convert it?

**Edit 2 :** There's one white space before the `+` sign. I'm using `get_the_excerpt` Wordpress function to get the string.

**Edit 3 :** After successfully removing the empty space and the `+` with `substr($s, 2);`, Here's what I get now :

```
$s == '#43;This is a string[...]'
```

**Wiki :** I had to remove 6 characters, I've tried `substr($s, 6);` and it's working well now. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: How have you used them? All of them should work.

Comment: If `$s = ltrim($s, '+')` doesn't work, then it isn't a `+`. If `$s = substr($s, 1);` doesn't work, then you're doing something very wrong

Comment: To remove certain character, i always use `explode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: `str_replace` WORKD check https://3v4l.org/sctrF

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove plus sign (+) from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552031/remove-plus-sign-from-string)

Comment: whats is problem in echo preg_replace('/\+/', '', $string);

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya It just don't do anything to the string!

Comment: It sounds as if you have a multi-byte string.  Detect your encoding and use the appropriate functions. i.e. mb_substr

Comment: This entire page will be misleading for researchers because the question details have evolved over time which rendered several answers incorrect.  Rather than DV'ing many incorrect answers, this page should be closed and deleted as it represents bad content on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ltrim has second parameter

```
$s = ltrim($s,'+');
```

edit:

if it is not working it means that there is sth else at the beginning of that string, eg. white spaces. You can check it by using `var_dump($s);` which shows you exactly what you have there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but just tried it and it doesn't replace it.

Comment: It replace - i checked. So maybe you only think that you have there string what you told us. Just show **exactly** what you have there by `var_dump($s);`

Comment: of course it works. @NaourassDerouichi probably have there sth else eg. white spaces and he doesn't see it or sth similar

Comment: Can you add your comment to the answer? Adding the fact that it can contains a white space, and inspecting with `var_dump` may help other people in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi added in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` like this:

```
$result = explode('+', $s)[0];
```

What this function actually does is, it removes the delimeter you specify as a first argument and breaks the string into smaller strings whenever that delimeter is found and places those strings in an array.

It's mostly used with multiple ocurrences of a certain delimeter but it will work in your case too.

For example:

```
$string = "This,is,a,string";
$results = explode(',', $string);
var_dump($results); //prints ['This', 'is', 'a', 'string' ]
```

So in your case since the plus sign appears ony once the result is in the zero index of the returned array (that contains only one element, your string obviously)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of different ways I can think of

[str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
$string = str_replace('+', '', $string);
```

[preg_replace](http://www.php.net/preg_replace)

```
$string = preg_replace('/^\+/', '', $string);
```

[ltrim](http://php.net/ltrim)

```
$string = ltrim($string, '+');
```

[substr](http://php.net/substr)

```
$string = substr($string, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
$s = '+This is a string';
echo ltrim($s,'+');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ltrim() or substr().
For example :

```
$output = ltrim($string, '+');
```

or you can use

```
$output = substr($string, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove multiple characters with trim.  Perhaps you were not re-assigning the outcome of your trim function.

```
<?php

$s = ' +This is a string[...]';
$s = ltrim($s, '+ ');
print $s;
```

Outputs:

```
This is a string[...]
```

`ltrim` in the above example removes all spaces and addition characters from the left hand side of the original string.